# Jaxb sequence with unordered types

Tags: collections, jaxb, sequence

Using a schema and XML file I'm trying to create an element of Type A, that can contain nested elements of type A,B, and C.  The element types A,B,and C are all extension of type X.  So I wanted to create a  inside of the type a element, and thought I could add any of elements A,B, or C in whatever order I wanted.  Only A can have nested elements.  I like this implementation because the ordering of the nested elements is important to our data model, and these elements will be a various order in the system.

```
<A>
    <B></B>
    <B></B>
    <A>
        <B></B>
        <B></B>
        <C></C>
        <C></C>
    </A>
    <C></C>
</A>
```

I tried doing a few things in the XSD file to make this legal.

```
<xs:complexType name="A">
   <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="X" >
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="a" type="A" minOccurs="0" />
         <xs:element name="b" type="B" minOccurs="0" />
         <xs:element name="c" type="C" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

And I tried making the sequence contain only elements of the abstract type X, thinking I could use the concrete types A B and C in the XML file, but that got flagged as an error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly you can use the `@XmlElementRef` annotation to leverage the XML schema concept of substitution groups.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html